# nginx rewrite to htaccess rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

How to make Basic Auth exclude a rewritten file?

```
location ~ "^/blank.gif" {
    auth_basic off;
}

location / {
    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solve!

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/blank.gif" noauth=1

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^blank.gif$ count.php

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthUserFile /home/admin/web/domain.com/public_html/.htpasswd

Order Deny,Allow
Satisfy any
Deny from all
Require valid-user
Allow from env=noauth
```